# Qt4.8: How to make LineEdit show text in uppercase always and still have a RegExp

Tags: regex, qt, qt4, qt4.8

I'm making a gui app on Qt 4.8 which contains some lineedits to let the user introduce some information.

Normally you can write in 4 different ways the text "hello":

1. Caps Off, no shift pressed = "hello"
2. Caps Off, shift pressed = "HELLO"
3. Caps ON, no shift pressed = "HELLO"
4. Caps ON, shift pressed = "hello"

What I want is that no matter how the user writes, the line edit must show it in caps always ("HELLO").

What I was using now is:

Myclass.cpp:

```
auto validatorA = new MyValidator(parent);
myLineEdit->setValidator(validatorA);
```

Myclass.h (after includes and before  `class MyClass: ...`)

```
 class MyValidator: public QValidator {
 public:
    MyValidator(QObject* parent=nullptr): QValidator(parent) {}
    State validate(QString& input, int&) const override {
      input = input.toUpper();
       return QValidator::Acceptable;
    }
 };
```

It works perfect but I also need this line edit to accept only letters, spaces and numbers (no symbols acepted) so after set the validatorA I need to set:

```
QRegExp rx("[A-Z\\.\\- 0-9]{0,30}");
QValidator *validator7 = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);
myLineEdit->setValidator(validator7);
```

I've noticed that the last validator designed is the one who decides the behaviour, so I can't use both.
If I use the validator7 it works fine but it fails with the case number 4: if caps on and presses shift, then nothing is written, its like if the user were not typing even if he is clubbing the keyboard.
So I don't know how to be able to set both validators (I hav eother line edits with other different RegExp).

So... how can I make my lineedits follow RegExp and show always text in caps no matter the keyboard combination of caps+shift?

Thank you so much

Comment: Ty for the downvote... still don't know if its because it is not usefull (I bet some much ppl found this problem) or because there is no search effort ( if that were the case, I were asking how can I do it instead of posting the code I already found/got/make)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the validator for input with the following modification

```
QRegExp rx("[a-z-A-Z\\.\\- 0-9]{0,30}");
QValidator *validator7 = new QRegExpValidator(rx, this);
ui->lineEdit->setValidator(validator7);
```

And for the upper case use the `textEdited` signal from the LineEdit like this

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textEdited(const QString &arg1)
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText(arg1.toUpper());
}
```

Comment: ohh I see, and can you help me with 2 more cases? 1.- `QRegExp rx3.setPattern("CD\\d{3,4}$");` where I expect something like CD123  and   2.- `rx9.setPattern("[0-9]{3}A[0-9]{0,5}");`  where I expect something like:123A12345  until now they were working fine but now I see I need to add the downcase too but if I write cd-CD it doesnt works

Comment: 1.`"(c|C){1,1}(D|d){1,1}\\d{3,4}$"` 2. `"[0-9]{3}[A|a][0-9]{0,5}"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want only show letters in caps mode - you can set custom font to lineedit with:

`QFont f = font();
f.setCapitalization(QFont::AllUppercase);
lineEdit->setFont(f);`

But you still need regex to validate input.

Answer (score 1):

The regexp doesn't come in contact with your uppercase code.
First define your regular expression in a validator and setValidator and then:
You can simply try this for showing the text in uppercase:

```
connect(lineEdit,SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)),this,SLOT(toUpper(QString)));
```

and in the definition of the slot:

```
void MainWidget::toUpper(QString txt)
{
    lineEdit.setText(txt.toUpper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect `QLineEdit` signal `textChanged()` with slot:

```
connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(toUpper(const QString &)));
```

And do like this:

```
void MainWindow::toUpper(const QString &text)
{
    QLineEdit *le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(sender());
    if (!le)
        return;
    le->setText(text.toUpper());
}
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: yes but as I said I needed to combine it with a QRegExp.